# Downvoter targeting questions so that they get removed by Roomba

Tags: discussion, moderation, down-votes

A downvoter has been targeting questions so that they get removed by Roomba. I don't know whether only my questions are targeted. Examples:

1. [History of the provisioned write capacity in DynamoDB beyond the last two weeks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/91982/9622)
2. [Column order in a DynamoDB table browsed through RazorSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/91970/9622)
3. [Maxing out the shared pool's memory by executing many UPDATE statements (ORA-04031)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/100567/9622)

Could this please stop? Thanks.

---

Here are the questions' details:

1. [History of the provisioned write capacity in DynamoDB beyond the last two weeks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/91982/9622)

> Is there any way to see the history of the provisioned write capacity for a DynamoDB table beyond the last two weeks? When I go to the Amazon AWS console, select a DynamoDB table and look at the monitoring tab, the time range does not allow me to go beyond two weeks. Is there any other place to look at that could give me a longer history?
>
> [image]

2. [Column order in a DynamoDB table browsed through RazorSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/91970/9622)

> I use RazorSQL to navigate in a DynamoDB database. What's the rationale behind the column order?
>
> [image]
>
> I am asking as the import tool uses the same order (which means if I import a CSV file it needs to be in the same ordering as the RazorSQL's column order):
>
> [image]
>
> I use RazorSQL 6.3.14 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

3. [Maxing out the shared pool's memory by executing many UPDATE statements (ORA-04031)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/100567/9622)

> I was executing a bunch of UPDATE statement. Around ~32.8K got executed and committed, then got the error:
>
> ```
> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-04031: unable to allocate 3896 bytes of shared memory ("shared pool","UPDATE COHORTS_A SET COHORT5...","sga heap(1,0)","kglsim object batch")
> ```
>
> This made me think that the SQL area on Oracle DB grew too much to the point of maxing out the shared pool's memory.
>
> Running the follow query would confirm it, but ironically and unsurprisingly I get the ORA-04031 error on it as well:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM (
> SELECT name, bytes/(1024*1024) MB FROM v$sgastat 
> WHERE  pool = 'shared pool'  ORDER BY bytes DESC)
> WHERE rownum < 11;
> ```
>
> What could have caused the shared pool to be full? If there's no room left in the SQL area cache, shouldn't older statements be removed?
>
> I am running Oracle 11gR2 11.2.0.3.
>
> Here are the SQL UPDATE statements I was executing and committing (I know I can optimize them):
>
> ```
> UPDATE COHORTS_A SET COHORT2 = 6 WHERE HADM_ID = 22800
> UPDATE COHORTS_A SET COHORT2 = 5 WHERE HADM_ID = 22801
> UPDATE COHORTS_A SET COHORT2 = 5 WHERE HADM_ID = 22802
> UPDATE COHORTS_A SET COHORT2 = 6 WHERE HADM_ID = 22803
> UPDATE COHORTS_A SET COHORT2 = 6 WHERE HADM_ID = 22804
> UPDATE COHORTS_A SET COHORT2 = 6 WHERE HADM_ID = 22805
> UPDATE COHORTS_A SET COHORT2 = 6 WHERE HADM_ID = 22806
> UPDATE COHORTS_A SET COHORT2 = 6 WHERE HADM_ID = 22807
> UPDATE COHORTS_A SET COHORT2 = 6 WHERE HADM_ID = 22808
> UPDATE COHORTS_A SET COHORT2 = 6 WHERE HADM_ID = 22809
> UPDATE COHORTS_A SET COHORT2 = 6 WHERE HADM_ID = 22810
> UPDATE COHORTS_A SET COHORT2 = 6 WHERE HADM_ID = 22811
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You're not being targeted personally.

The question of old questions with zero score and no answers came up recently in chat when we were watching the total questions counter approach 100,000.

I was curious about how and when exactly this process works so I've been using my spare votes to drop such questions below the auto deletion threshold. I hadn't noticed that three of the questions belonged to you, but they all seemed worthy of a down vote to me.

Do you feel these old unanswered questions add value to the site? You are still looking for answers? They do kinda look abandoned I must say.

If you *are* still interested in answers you should edit your questions to improve them if possible, add a bounty, vote to undelete where necessary etc.

Otherwise, they do just look old & abandoned and only exist because no one voted (down, close, delete ... anything).

---

Thanks for self-answering one of the questions and voting to undelete the others. I made a couple of small edits and agreed with the undeletion for the time being. The conditions for auto deletion are no longer met, but that could change again of course.

Comment: Thanks, the deletion script has some thresholds indeed. If one disagrees with it, I believe that should be raised on Meta SE instead of downvoting the questions with the intent of triggering the deletion script. Yes, I'm still interested in reading answers about it. No ideas why these questions are worthy of getting downvoted.

Comment: Right but I don't disagree with it, just curious about the details and what options the author has etc. Anyway, if you're interested in answers you should edit your questions to improve them if possible, add a bounty perhaps, and so on. Vote to undelete where necessary. Otherwise they do look old & abandoned and only exist because no one voted (down, close, delete ... anything).

Comment: Thanks, I don't wish to bump them as there are many other good questions too, I just wish they stay alive in case someone else shares the same interest and happens to know the answer. But now that you mentioned that, I feel the deletion script should have one more condition based on whether the OP is still around. Or have some button that the OP could click on to indicate they are still interested in knowing the answer.

Comment: Yes, that's an interesting point. A prompt before auto deletion might be useful. Can you vote to undelete the already roomba'd ones?

Comment: thanks, I just casted the votes,. Note that votes to undelete where necessary typically don't results in the question getting undeleted unless a mod is willing to help. And even a question gets undeleted, it'll get deleted again 7 days later by the same deletion script, unless conditions aren't meet anymore.

Comment: Yes indeed. That's one of the reasons I suggest improving the questions - it gives fresh eyes and a chance for people to change their votes. The lack of deletion and undeletion review queues is a longstanding irritation, but they do appear in the 10k tools.